# How to reset the main page in a Vue.js app

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, html-framework-7

I have come a long way with Vue so I am finding it frustrating to not be able to work this one out.

In my App, I use a main.vue page that capture the users login, authorises the user, and verifies the data. Depending on the data it then offers the user a 'sync' option or the menu. That is working great.

Our UI then requires the user to move through a couple pages to complete the task. On completion I want mhm to return to that menu view within main.vue - the child page view are then no longer relevant - We don't want them to go 'back' once at the menu. We want them to start the process again. Like This:

```
Menu ---> Step 1 ---> Step 2 --- > Step 3 |
   |                                      |
   | < -------------------------------------
```

If I add a 'Home' page in the router and go there, then I get a NEW Vue instance nested within.

How do I reset the DOM to remove those views from the history and just go back to my original menu?
Or is there a way to reset the  section within the DOM?

Note - This is a Framework7 / Vue / Webpack / Cordova app

Appreciate your suggestions

Comment: I am learning Vue+Framework7 and am also experiencing some pain with routing. In your case, since each View is a router, with its own notion of history, wouldn't it make more sense for your Steps 1-3 be in their own View?  So you would show the Steps View, the user proceeds through its pages, then you could discard that View (somehow) and be left back at your main Menu view?